# Hibernate partially populated object with projections

Tags: java, hibernate

My question is same exact issue like this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175399/hibernate-result-transformer?rq=1).

Assume we have entity like

```
public class Employee {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Address getAddress();  
}
```

With the help of createCriteria and Projections we are trying to get id,name from users and city from address table.

The issue we are having is, city is not being set to address object city property.

Here is the code we tried:

```
 Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
                    .add(Projections.property("Name"), "Name")
                    .add(Projections.property("address.city"), "address.city"))
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("address.city"))
                    .createAlias("address", "address")
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class));
```

Based on `JBNizet` comment on above question I understood that partially objects are bad idea, but If I am mandated to do that how can I achieve it? Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer.html), and define a constructor like the following in your entity:

```
public Employee(Long id, String name, String city) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = new Address();
    this.address.setCity(city);
}
```

Or, (and this is my preferred solution, because it avoids reflection and allows refactoring the code with less risk) dont't use any result transformer and construct your instances yourself:

```
List<Object[]> rows = criteria.list();
List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>(rows.size());
for (Object[] row : rows) {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setId((Long) row[0]);
    e.setName((String) row[1]);
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setCity((String) row[2]);
    e.setAddress(address);
    result.add(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet. I will try may be second approach.

Comment: While doing this solution I ended up in strange situation. One issue is, my criteria sometimes populates City, sometimes ZIPcode, Sometime both. That criteria section will be if/else case. In this scenario, how can I use Object[] to identify whether my query is right now using ZIPCODE (or) CITY (or) BOTH? Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: If you know what to query, you should also know what to populate. Simple `if` blocks should do. You could also have three "Populator" instances, and create the appropriate one at the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
                    .add(Projections.property("name"), "name")
                    .add(Projections.property("address.city"), "addressCity"))
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("address.city"))
                    .createAlias("address", "address")
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class));
```

And also add setter for addressCity in Employee class

```
public void setAddressCity( String addressCity ){
    address.setCity(addressCity);
}
```

No need to mention that the constructor of the Employee, should also instantiate the Address object.

Comment: I do not think this will work. We might get error about addressCity not identified in Employee.class